# Tweet rate limit hit nodeRED

Tags: twitter, limit, rate, node-red

I have a nodeRED flow with one Twitter input node. I am searching for my @twitterhandle in the "for" box. It is set to check all public tweets. As soon as I deploy, I get the message:

```
msg : string [20]
tweet rate limit hit
```

in the debug tab. Even if I switch it to "the tweets of who you follow", I get this message every 10 seconds in the debug tab. I just want to check for tweets being directed at me, from anyone. I am sending just one tweet to myself and I still have this problem. I don't understand the error message, either, since my handle is 15 characters, not 20.
Please help me!

[edit: Even when it is not deployed, I get this message. I have also tried using a different Twitter account. I have also tried deleting the Twitter node and redeploying.]

[edit2: Looks like after the 15 minute limit window, the error subsides if I set it to "the tweets of who you follow", but I really want to get tweets from people I'm not following.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is related to how many times you hit the API endpoint, not the number of tweets (which will always just be a sample anyway given how the API works).

The more you change your flow and redeploy the more times you will hit the API endpoint and the more likely you are to see the message. The node if left unchanged, will back off for a while and try again later and as you see it does work properly if left.

Pick the options you want, deploy and leave it be (the more you try and "fix" things the more likely to API rate limited)

Comment: Brilliant, that seems to have sorted it. Thanks very much.